# Custom field value update in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In drupal I have created custom field where I'm storing some information
[admin people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5CAs.png)

Hello guys I want to update the value of reviewed from `no` or `none` to `yes` when selecting the custom bulk operation reviewed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module. After enabling the module, create a new view in structure->views:

- Enter a **name** for your view
- Select **"Show Users sorted by unsorted"**
- Check **"Create a page"**, in "Display format" select **Table**.
- Items to display: **leave empty** to show all your users
- Hit **Continue and edit**

In the "Fields" section, add the fields you need for the user:

- Click on **add**
- Enter **"user:"** in search
- **Select the fields** you want in your table
- Click on **apply(all displays)**
- Click on **apply(all displays) again**

Now we have to add the custom bulk operation field. Again in the "Fields" section:

- click on **add**
- Select **"Bulk operations: User" field**
- Click on **apply(all displays)**
- Under "Selected Bulk Operations", check **"Modify entity values"**
- In "Operation Settings", **select your custom field** (reviewed? in your case)
- Hit **apply(all displays)**

You can Reorder your fields to put the "Bulk operations: User" field first, and then you hit "Save".
You can see the table by clicking **"view Page"** on the right, or by going to the url **{Your drupal base url}/{your page name}**

For more details, you can see the module documentation here : [VBO for Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1591352)

Answer (score 0):

Much of views_bulk_operations is now in core (celebrate!), but not the features you would need for this scenario.

Now you can git the benefit from https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_edit